# Excel - Find a value in an array and return the value of the cell next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a table in which I want to search for "Item" in the whole Array of E1:X100 and return the value next to the match in the "Output" row.

As an example: I want to search for the Item "AC06" (marked yellow) in the whole rest of the sheet - find it in I8 and output the value in the cell next to it (marked green) to the cell C13.

[See Example Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWvLC.png)

I experimented with an index match without success. One way to solve it would be of course to copy all of the Items and Descriptions under each other and do a Vlookup - this, however, is not the real Solution we need.

Comment: Can you please show the formulas you tried to use? And outline what error, if any, you got?

Comment: Are AMI, AQU, ATT, etc all on the same row? Use a two-dimensioned INDEX and find the appropriate LOOKUP AND return column with a COUPLE OF MATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest some [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs.

```
=INDEX(H:AC, MATCH(D10, INDEX(H:AC,0,MATCH(E10, H$4:AC$4, 0)), 0),MATCH(E10,H$4:AC$4,0)+1)
```

[image: =INDEX(H:AC, MATCH(D8, INDEX(H:AC,0,MATCH(E8, H$2:AC$2, 0)), 0),MATCH(E8,H$2:AC$2,0)+1)]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the example above, in which column would "ITEM" be and in which cell the example formula?